# How can you can calculate the time span between two time entries in a file using a shell script?

Tags: linux, unix

In a Linux script: I have a file that has two time entries for each message within the file. A 'received time' and a 'source time'. there are hundreds of messages within the file.

I want to calculate the elapsed time between the two times.

```
2014-07-16T18:40:48Z  (received time)
2014-07-16T18:38:27Z  (source time)
```

The source time is 3 lines after the received time, not that it matters.

info on the input data:

The input has a lines are as follows:

```
TimeStamp:        2014-07-16T18:40:48Z
```

2 lines later: a bunch of messages in one line and within each line, multiple times is:

```
sourceTimeStamp="2014-07-16T18:38:27Z"
```

Comment: What timezone is that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU's `date` (not busybox's), you can give difference in seconds with:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$(date -d '2014-07-16T18:40:48Z' '+%s')
B=$(date -d '2014-07-16T18:38:27Z' '+%s')
echo "$(( A - B )) seconds"
```

For busybox's `date` and `ash` (modern probably / BusyBox v1.21.0):

```
#!/bin/ash
A=$(busybox date -d '2014-07-16 18:40:48' '+%s')
B=$(busybox date -d '2014-07-16 18:38:27' '+%s')
echo "$(( A - B )) seconds"
```

Comment: On my CentOS box, I had to strip that `T` in order to have a valid input for `date`.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu Not Z too?

Comment: Nope. The Z seemed fine.

Comment: I see. busybox's `date` doesn't want it.

Comment: I tried this and it worked one entry. I need to figure out to make it work multiple times through out an awk output file.

Comment: Well that could be another question I believe. :)

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use `date` like this (e.g.)

```
date +%s --date="2014-07-16T18:40:48Z"
```

to convert both timestamps into a unix timestamp. Getting the time difference between them is then reduced to a simple subtraction.

Does this help?

Comment: that is an interesting way try it. I will see how it works tomorrow morning. an awk script puts in it an output file and separates the fields with spaces. I should mention there is other data fields from the awk script in the output file. but I want to extract the times and calculate the elapsed time between time. I want to verify there is a 5 min delay with all messages within the awk output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`. The following script searches for the lines of interest, converts the time value into a UNIX timestamp and saves them in the `start`, `end` variables. At the end of the script the difference will get calculated and printed:

*timediff.awk*:

```
/received time/ {
    "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline end 
}

/source time/ {
    "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline start
     exit
}

END {
    printf "%s seconds in between", end - start
}
```

Execute it like this:

```
awk -f timediff.awk log.file
```

Output:

```
141 seconds in between
```

Comment: I use awk to extract the time fields into a file. I want to calculate the time span between the two times.

Comment: This is what solution does.

Comment: I ran it as you had it, but returned an error:

sh : line 1: ?xml: no such file or directory
0 seconds between

the only difference is the names.
/recieved time/ is /Timestamp:/
&
/source time/ is /sourceTimestamp=/

Comment: Those are the field exact names that precedes the time in the file.

Comment: /TimeStamp:/ {
    "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline end 
}

/sourceTimeStamp:/ {
    "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline start
     exit
}

END {
    printf "%s seconds in between", end - start
}

Comment: Im sorry i dont know how to enter on here to show the exact format.

Comment: The input has a line as follows:
             TimeStamp:          2014-07-16T18:40:48Z

2 lines later:

a bunch of messages in one line and within each line,multiple times is:
 sourceTimeStamp="2014-07-16 18:38:27Z"

Comment: "Im sorry i dont know how to enter on here to show the exact format." It's simple: Edit your question ( and probably delete comments, posting such stuff in comments will never being readable)

Comment: yes. and the first one...  /Timestamp:/ has spaces before the time. while /sourceTimestamp=/ has quotes. I updated the question.